# Change position of infoWindow in osmdroid with bonuspack

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid with the bonuspack.

Right now the infoWindow appears above the marker, is there a way to let it appear right of the marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should extend `Marker` class and override [the `showInfoWindow` method](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/920b5faec30c1fa1be3bca214387966bc4252784/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/Marker.java#L209). There you can recalculate `offsetX` and `offsetY` to get what you need.

Comment: THERE it is! Thank you so much, this solves even other problems so complicated that I wasn't even able to formulate a question about it XD

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can use setInfoWindowAnchor(u, v). 
(u,v) being the position of the bubble anchor, in marker icon coordinates (0,0)(1,1). 
To set the anchor outside the icon, on the right, u can be higher than 1.

But the solution from Nikolai can be simpler, depending on what you need.